# google script - same script for 3 users or one script for all users

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google script to add/read and delete records from a sheet using doGet via a HTML form.The script is deployed as access by anyone incl. anonymous.

I have 3 users who need to use this script.

Do i have to create 3 separate scripts- one for each or can all 3 use the same script

Comment: By your own statement anyone can access this web app and execute it as though they are you, so why would you need three scripts?

Comment: You might want to use LockService.